# Php Login submission

Tags: php, post, authentication

This is some PHP code for login on a page.

```
if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In") {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email)."' AND password='$md5' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    print_r($row);  
}
```

But when I submit LOGIN it doesn't work.

Comment: What is $md5?
Also, can you show some more code?

Comment: By "doesn't work" you mean...? Did you already tried to echo the `$query`and paste it into phpMyAdmin to see what it returns?

Comment: if you not familier with PDO, try this, easier to use and it is using PDO: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Answer (score 0):

```
$userCheck = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_email =?",$_POST['user']);
if(count($userCheck)===1){
    //we found a match
    $data = $userCheck[0];
    //now we compare the encryted password
    if(crypt($_POST['password'],$data['users_hash'])===$data['users_hash']){
        //the password match... the encrypted password
        $logged=1;
        //so we set the cookie if the user checked the cookie box
        //cookie and session code

        echo 1;
    }else{
        //meaning wrong password
        echo 2;
    }
}else{
    //wrong username
    echo 0;
}
```

I am using a custom function working with PDO... I can post the function here if you need to

custom query function using PDO

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */){
    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0);

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }

    // execute SQL statement
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

    // return result set's rows, if any
    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

to use it, see the synthax on the top

or:
ex:

```
$check = query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=?",$text);
```

Comment: I don't know how PDO works. It will be my pleasure to learn something from your post of PDO function.. @Jayo2k

Comment: PDO simplify mysql query compared to the original mysql_fetch, mysql_connect... But the function I have simplyfy it even more, calling query is all you have to do, here the code in my updated answer